# Sonarqube scanner for msbuild pre-processing failed

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

From Jenkins I want to analyze my .net projects.

I have configured **SonarQube scanner for MSbuild** by using "Install automatically" in 'manage jenkins --> global tool configuration'. For job Configuration I have used the [SonarQube documentation here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE53/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforJenkins-ConfiguringaSonarQubeScannerusingenvironmentvariables).

I don't understand why I am getting the following error even after I have set my Project key and Project Name correct as reference link is showing.

> ERROR-
>
> Pre-processing started.
>
> Preparing working directories...
>
> 16:50:06.699  16:50:06.695  Unrecognized command line argument:
>   sonar.projectVersion
>
> 16:50:06.699  16:50:06.696  Unrecognized command line argument: =
>
> 16:50:06.699  16:50:06.696  Unrecognized command line argument: 1.0
>
> 16:50:06.699  16:50:06.696  Unrecognized command line argument: -
>
> 16:50:06.699  16:50:06.697  Unrecognized command line argument: Build
>
> 16:50:06.699  16:50:06.697  Unrecognized command line argument: Number
>
> 16:50:06.699  16:50:06.697  Unrecognized command line argument:
>   ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}
>
> 16:50:06.7  Expecting at least the following command line argument:
>   - SonarQube project key
>
> When connecting to a SonarQube server earlier than version 6.1, the
>   following command line arguments are also required:
>   - SonarQube project name
>
> - SonarQube project version
>
> The full path to a settings file can also be supplied. If it is not
>   supplied, the exe will attempt to locate a default settings file in
>   the same directory as the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild.
>
> Use '/?' or '/h' to see the help message. 16:50:06.7  Pre-processing
>   failed. Exit code: 1
>
> ERROR: Execution of SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild failed (exit code 1)
>   Finished: FAILURE

Comment: it would be helpful to know something about your build/analysis configuration

Comment: we simply developed .net project (windows and web application) in c#. we are using GITLAB as SCM and CI tool is Jenkins.   SonarQube server(6.5) and GITLAB  integrated with Jenkins(2.7x) and for scanning project i've configured Sonarqube scanner for MSBuild(4.0.2.892) "Install automatically" in jenkins's global tool configuration.

Comment: MSBuild 14 ,we are using to build project.

Comment: More, my SonarQube server ,MSbuild and Jenkins is running with Windows server 2012..